# Displaying a message when resultset is empty

Tags: php, sql-server, database

In the following code, if the resultset is empty, the code continues to process the result. What I want instead is to just display "Query failed." when there are no results.

```
$connInfo = array('UID'=>$user, 'PWD'=>$passwd, 'Database'=>$database);
$dbconn = sqlsrv_connect($server, $connInfo);

if($dbconn === false){
    die("<br />Error connecting to the database.<br />");
}
//SQL Query
$query = "SELECT ... FROM somehwere";

//Run Query
$qresult = sqlsrv_query($dbconn, $query);
if($qresult === false) {
    die('Query failed.');
}

?>
...more code...
```

Answer (score 4):

$qresult will contain an empty result set if no rows are found, but it still won't evaluate to false.

Try this function instead:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-num-rows.php

So:

```
if(!sqlsrv_num_rows($qresult)) {
    die('Query failed.');
}
```

Instead of:

```
if($qresult === false) {
    die('Query failed.');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It does not display "Query Failed" because the query has not failed. It just returns 0 rows. So, the solution will be to use:

```
$row_count = sqlsrv_num_rows( $qresult);
if ($row_count > 0){
// display stuff
}
else{
// throw exception
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks.  I got it to work using sqlsrv_has_rows() function.

```
if($qresult !== NULL) {
    $rows = sqlsrv_has_rows($qresult);
    if($rows === true) {
        //display success
    } else {
        //display error
    }
}
```

For some reason I couldn't get the sqlsrv_num_rows() to work properly for me.